# Android SDK location wrong after updating to Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

At some point during the various Android Studio releases prior to 1.5, the SDK was moved out of c:\Program Files (x86). After updating to 1.5 I encountered many weird error messages related to the AVD emulator being unable to start, for example:
- This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file
- ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
- PANIC: ...message about the emulator

I have been unable to find any answers so I am answering it myself.

Comment: Please add more information about the error messages received.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that Android Studio 1.5 by default seems to move the SDK back into c:\Program Files (x86) so now you'll have two SDK paths. There may be a simpler solution, but the first thing I did was to fix the SDK to point back to a different location: c:\android-sdk-win:

In Android Studio, go to File>Settings>Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK and change the Android SDK Location there.

Now you'll probably need to run the SDK Manager to re-download the various packages that Android Studio 1.5 wanted after updating.